# react-navigation v2 como enviar component pelos params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Estou tentando fazer o envio de um component para uma nova rota via params, mas da maneira que estou fazendo não funciona. Alguém sabe me indicar meu erro?

**Component A**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ModalInput', {
          input: {
            component: <Input />,
          }
        });
```

**Component ModalInput**

```
    ...
render() {
    const params = this.props.navigation.state.params;

return (
<View>
params.input.component.children()
...
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que está indicando?

Comment: utilizando children() como função, ele indica que a função não existe, se eu tento como atributo nao retorna nada

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o que você precisa é:

**Componente A**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ModalInput', {
    itemId: <Input />,
});
```

**ModalInput**

```
const params = this.props;
const item = params.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID'); /* itemId sendo o nome do parametro e NO-ID o valor padrão */
```

fonte: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html